# AES-GCM 256bit for SSL on nginx

Tags: security, ssl, nginx

Does an option exist for AES-GCM 256bit encryption for SSL connections with nginx? If so, how can I configure this as the only cipher used with my server?

(I'm hardening my router, so requiring the latest browser isn't an obstacle for my implementation.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is the cipher suite you're looking for:

```
$ openssl ciphers -v 'ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:ECDH+3DES:DH+3DES:RSA+AES:RSA+3DES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS'
DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA      SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA      SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA    SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=3DES(168) Mac=SHA1
AES256-SHA              SSLv3 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
AES128-SHA              SSLv3 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
DES-CBC3-SHA            SSLv3 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=3DES(168) Mac=SHA1
```

Adding this to Nginx should give you what you want:

```
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers On;
ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:ECDH+3DES:DH+3DES:RSA+AES:RSA+3DES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS;
```

Be sure to test these changes using [Qualys’s SSL Server Test](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/).

#### References

- [Hardening Your Web Server’s SSL Ciphers](https://hynek.me/articles/hardening-your-web-servers-ssl-ciphers/)